# Adding 50a circuit to an existing panel

Tags: electrical

I have an existing 200a service in my home.  The panel is located in the garage.  Over the years I have added several 15a circuits.  I have an air compressor I want to install in the garage that requires a 50a 240v circuit.  Will it require a sub panel, or can it be installed on the existing main panel?  If I need a sub, will it require an upgrade from my service provider?
Either way, I plan on getting an electrician to do the work.  I just want to know what I’m facing.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the garage attached? Do you have a sub panel in the garage already? How much are you currently drawing from the main panel and how much space is left? Does it have room for a double ganged 240?

Comment: What make and model is the existing panel? Can you get us the square footage of your house + how much current your HVAC system pulls and what your other major draws are, as well as how many kitchen small appliance circuits you have?

Answer (score 2):

If you have 2 open slots in your existing panel you could put a breaker in no sub panel is needed. If you do not have open slots you can add couple of double stuff breakers to open up space. For the 50A 240 circuit if the existing main panel is rated for doubles.

Comment: As Ed said. To add a sub-panel you would still need two open slots in the main unless you have main lugs rated for two conductors.